# Crystal Reports Script

Tags: crystal-reports

With the following script we're getting the error
'A Number or Currency Amount is Required Here'

Unfortunately just cannot see where the error is 
The value {?ProdSubCat} is a parameter with multiple selections - so I am assuming it has become an array.

```
numbervar Index;

for Index:=1 to ubound({?ProdSubCat}) do 
(

If {?ProdSubCat}[Index] = 14 then
 crDoubleLine
Else 
  crNoLine
);
```

Comment: You can comment the statement one by one to see which statement has problem.

Comment: @RobDavies What are the types of crDoubleLine and crNoLine variables?

Comment: We're working in a border control and crDoubleLine and crNoLine  are the recommended settings in crystal. This is a test script. Long term variables would be better